# Groovy: Optimize code to find duplicate elements

Tags: performance, optimization, groovy

I have `invoiceList` as below which is a `List<Map<String:String>>` and am trying to findout if all the invoices have same `SENDER_COUNTRY` and `CLIENT_COUNTRY` or not, if not it will add message to JSON array

```
[
    [INVOICE_DATE:20150617, INVOICE_NUMBER:617151,SENDER_COUNTRY:USA, CLIENT_COUNTRY:USA]
    [INVOICE_DATE:20150617, INVOICE_NUMBER:617152,SENDER_COUNTRY:CAD, CLIENT_COUNTRY:MEX]
    [INVOICE_DATE:20150617, INVOICE_NUMBER:617153,SENDER_COUNTRY:CAD, CLIENT_COUNTRY:MEX]
]

JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
def senderCountry = invoiceList[0]['SENDER_COUNTRY']
def clientCountry  = invoiceList[0]['CLIENT_COUNTRY']
invoiceList.each{ it ->
if(it['SENDER_COUNTRY'] != senderCountry)
  jsonArray.add((new JSONObject()).put("SENDER_COUNTRY","Multiple sender Countries Associated"));
 if(it['CLIENT_COUNTRY'] != clientCountry)
  jsonArray.add((new JSONObject()).put("CLIENT_COUNTRY","Multiple Client Countries Associated"));
}
```

I feel this code can be refactored/optimized to a better version in Groovy, can someone please help me with it?

Comment: RanPaul, see if solution provided is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another version to achieve the same.

```
def invoiceList = [
  [INVOICE_DATE:20150617, INVOICE_NUMBER:617151,SENDER_COUNTRY:'USA', CLIENT_COUNTRY:'USA'],
  [INVOICE_DATE:20150617, INVOICE_NUMBER:617152,SENDER_COUNTRY:'CAD', CLIENT_COUNTRY:'MEX'],
  [INVOICE_DATE:20150617, INVOICE_NUMBER:617153,SENDER_COUNTRY:'CAD', CLIENT_COUNTRY:'MEX']
]

def getFilteredList = { map ->
    map.collect{ k,v -> invoiceList.countBy{ it."$k" }.findAll{it.value > 1}.collectEntries{[it.key,v] } }
}

//You may change the description in the values of below map
def findEntries = [CLIENT_COUNTRY: 'Multiple Client Countries found', SENDER_COUNTRY: 'Multiple Sender Countries found']
println groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(getFilteredList(findEntries))
```

**Output:**

```
[{"MEX":"Multiple Client Countries found"},{"CAD":"Multiple Sender Countries found"}]
```

You can quickly try online <kbd>[Demo](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5150590346723328)</kbd>

**EDIT:** OP requested for additional information saying it should also return empty if all `client country` or `sender country` are same.

Use below script:

```groovy
def invoiceList = [
  [INVOICE_DATE:20150617, INVOICE_NUMBER:617151,SENDER_COUNTRY:'CAD', CLIENT_COUNTRY:'USA'],
  [INVOICE_DATE:20150617, INVOICE_NUMBER:617152,SENDER_COUNTRY:'CAD', CLIENT_COUNTRY:'MEX'],
  [INVOICE_DATE:20150617, INVOICE_NUMBER:617153,SENDER_COUNTRY:'CAD', CLIENT_COUNTRY:'MEX']
]

def getFilteredList = { map->
    map.collect{ k,v -> invoiceList.countBy{ it."$k" }.findAll{it.value > 1  && (it.value != invoiceList.size())}.collectEntries{ [it.key,v] } }.findAll{it.size()>0}
}

//You may change the descript in the values of below map
def findEntries = [CLIENT_COUNTRY: 'Multiple Client Countried found', SENDER_COUNTRY: 'Multiple Sender Countries found']
println groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(getFilteredList(findEntries))​
```

Quickly try online <kbd>[Demo](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5103198402510848)</kbd>

**EDIT2:** OP further request modification to change the output as

```
[ {"message", "Multiple clients, Multiple sender"}]
```

```groovy
def invoiceList = [
  [INVOICE_DATE:20150617, INVOICE_NUMBER:617151,SENDER_COUNTRY:'CAD1', CLIENT_COUNTRY:'USA'],
  [INVOICE_DATE:20150617, INVOICE_NUMBER:617152,SENDER_COUNTRY:'CAD', CLIENT_COUNTRY:'MEX'],
  [INVOICE_DATE:20150617, INVOICE_NUMBER:617153,SENDER_COUNTRY:'CAD', CLIENT_COUNTRY:'MEX']
]

def getFilteredList = { map->
    def result = map.collect{ k,v -> invoiceList.countBy{ it."$k" }.findAll{it.value > 1  && (it.value != invoiceList.size())}.collect{ v } }.findAll{it.size()>0}
    result ? [[message : result.flatten().join(',') ]] : []
}

//You may change the descript in the values of below map
def findEntries = [CLIENT_COUNTRY: 'Multiple Client Countried found', SENDER_COUNTRY: 'Multiple Sender Countries found']
println groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(getFilteredList(findEntries))​
```

Comment: it doesnt work if all the `SENDER_COUNTRY` values are same and  all the `CLIENT_COUNTRY` values are same

Comment: @RanPaul, I do not see such behaviour. It does work as desired, double checked it. See [demo](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5191556013228032). Or you show the data  / result (add screen shot if possible)

Comment: @RanPaul, have you rechecked it? Is that what you wanted to optimize or looking for something more? If that resolves, appreciate if it is accepted as answer.

Comment: @RanPaul, have you got chance to check it - http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5191556013228032

Comment: yes, if all the sender countries are same and if all the client countries are same then json array should be empty

Comment: Where was it mentioned? All it is mentioned that if it occurs more than once, should be added json array. Isn't it so?

Comment: I did metion in the question right as `am trying to findout if all the invoices have same SENDER_COUNTRY and CLIENT_COUNTRY or not`

Comment: Ok, what to do if all SENDER_COUNTRY is same and CLIENT_COUNTRY have two same?

Comment: then json array should have one message saying `Multiple client countries associated`

Comment: @RanPaul, please see the `EDIT` in the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143988/discussion-between-rao-and-ranpaul).

Comment: @RanPaul, please see the improved update in `EDIT2` .

Answer (score 2):

What about this (note that my answer does not improve on performance):

```
def invoiceList = [
  [INVOICE_DATE:20150617, INVOICE_NUMBER:617151,SENDER_COUNTRY:'USA', CLIENT_COUNTRY:'USA'],
  [INVOICE_DATE:20150617, INVOICE_NUMBER:617152,SENDER_COUNTRY:'CAD', CLIENT_COUNTRY:'MEX'],
  [INVOICE_DATE:20150617, INVOICE_NUMBER:617153,SENDER_COUNTRY:'CAD', CLIENT_COUNTRY:'MEX']
]

def jsonarray = []
if (invoiceList.countBy{ it.CLIENT_COUNTRY }.size > 1)
     jsonarray << [CLIENT_COUNTRY: "Multiple client countries associated"]
if (invoiceList.countBy{ it.SENDER_COUNTRY }.size > 1)
     jsonarray << [SENDER_COUNTRY: "Multiple sender countries associated"]

groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(jsonarray)
// Result: [{"CLIENT_COUNTRY":"Multiple client countries associated"},{"SENDER_COUNTRY":"Multiple sender countries associated"}]
```

Comment: doing this is the equivalent of looping the entire array to map to -> CLIENT_COUNTRY, then the unique is looping again to find the duplicates. This is much worst than the original.

Comment: @Raphael I agree with your comment, but I got the feeling this question was about style "a better version of Groovy", not performance.

Comment: ideed, it might

Answer (score 1):

If you can add a new library to your project, you could use GPars:

```
@Grab(group='org.codehaus.gpars', module='gpars', version='1.0.0') 
import static groovyx.gpars.GParsPool.withPool

def invoiceList = [
    [INVOICE_DATE:20150617, INVOICE_NUMBER:617151,SENDER_COUNTRY:USA, CLIENT_COUNTRY:USA]
    [INVOICE_DATE:20150617, INVOICE_NUMBER:617152,SENDER_COUNTRY:CAD, CLIENT_COUNTRY:MEX]
    [INVOICE_DATE:20150617, INVOICE_NUMBER:617153,SENDER_COUNTRY:CAD, CLIENT_COUNTRY:MEX]
]

def jsonArray = []
def senderCountry = invoiceList[0]['SENDER_COUNTRY']
def clientCountry  = invoiceList[0]['CLIENT_COUNTRY']

withPool( 4 ) {             
    invoiceList.eachParallel{  
        if(it['SENDER_COUNTRY'] != senderCountry)
            jsonArray.add((new JSONObject()).put("SENDER_COUNTRY","Multiple sender Countries Associated"));
        if(it['CLIENT_COUNTRY'] != clientCountry)
            jsonArray.add((new JSONObject()).put("CLIENT_COUNTRY","Multiple Client Countries Associated"))
    }         
}

​
```

This will create a thread pool with 4 workers and they will scan the invoiceList in parallel.